# Reduce Service layer and DAO in Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I came across a SO question which says that Service and DAO could have the same content, and after exploring my functions in both Service and DAO, the functions are exactly the same. I know that the DAO is for DB queries, and the Service is for logic question, but how can I reduce the functions of each of those as I have this in Service :

```
public interface PlatformService {
    public void addPlatform(Platform platform);
    public void updatePlatform(Platform platform);
    public Platform getPlatformById(int id);
    public List<Platform> getPlatform();

}
```

and in DAO :

```
    public void addPlatform(Platform platform);
    public void updatePlatform(Platform platform);
    public List<Platform> getPlatform();
    public Platform getPlatformById(int id);

}
```

that are *exactly* the same! I don't know, if removing anything from a part will change the app speed or the app won't be functional at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you can directly create ServiceImpl without Service interface, but it's not increase the speed significantly. Then you get disadvantage when the data access is changed.

The main reason you create Service layer is to maintain the ServiceImpl when the data access is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove any part from, it won't function properly, but it won't improve the speed. The service layer is *optional*, you can write your app without it.

Comment: If I remove it from Sevice it won't work but you say it is optional .. ?

Comment: yes, it's optional, if you remove it you have to replace it with DAO or Repository.

Comment: my question is about WHAT to remove from each, not if I remove any of thsoe

Comment: you can't remove anything unless it has dependencies removed from other parts.

Comment: I know .. you don't understand the real question in here.

Comment: What is the *the real question*?